# Why did Lupin the Third change its target audience in recent years?

Tags: lupin-the-third

I just finished watching a lot of the original **Lupin the Third** television series from the 1970s.

Then I watched [**Lupin the Third: Mine Fujiko to Iu Onna**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/13203/Lupin_the_Third:_Mine_Fujiko_to_Iu_Onna) and [**Lupin the Third: Jigen Daisuke no Bohyou**](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23293/Lupin_the_IIIrd:_Jigen_Daisuke_no_Bohyou). These two were my stand out favourites. They both also happen to be tagged as Seinen on MAL, unlike the rest of the Lupin shows which are Shounen.

Why was there a sudden change in the focus of the series?
Or better yet, why isn't Lupin a Seinen series to begin with? Personally, I think it works much better as a Seinen series.

I also noticed that they're doing [another Shounen series](http://myanimelist.net/anime/27947/Lupin_III_%282015%29) this year.
Didn't people like the Seinen ones?

Comment: Wow, did you watch all 23 + 155 + 50 = 228 episodes from all 3 parts of Lupin TV series?

Comment: Parts 1 and 2, skipped 3 as they started to drag.